# Creating a dynamic range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need some help in creating this dynamic range slider since I'm not so good at back-end coding.

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/dynamicrangeslider_zpsb2ae70b4.jpg

Basically the objective here is if the user check the option for 90 pesos and above or 90 pesos to 1000 pesos the slider will change the min and max range.

Here is what i have started.

Javascript/Jquery

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
jQuery( "#slider-range" ).slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    step:5,
    values: [ 0, 300 ],
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - Php" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
    }

});
    jQuery( "#amount" ).val( "Php" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
    " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
});
</script>
```

All i need to do is to know what to replace or what to add.

Comment: If you are trying to figure out how to change the min/max after the slider has been created it would be (for example) `$("#slider-range").slider("option", "min", 10 );`

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass those variables in:

```
var minimumValue = 0; // Get the minimum pesos somehow
var maximumValue = 1000; // Get the maximum pesos somehow

...
range: true,
min: minimumValue,
max: maximumValue,
...
```

Hard to know what more to give you than this without more code. (where you're getting these values from, ids, etc.)

Comment: ah ok hmm i get your logic but how do pass a value from html. Do i need to use if else like for example. If the user choose option 1 which 1 to 1000 pesos. The min and max value will change

Comment: I'd need more code from your html page to determine how to do that. Do you have these values when the page is loaded?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm doing this on magento. So all the pages are chopped. Hmmmm